# How to add a DLL to a VS2010 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a DLL that I compiled from source (gdal). I have a simple C++ Win32 console project that has one source file, but I want to link against that DLL. Currently, when I try to run the project, it compiles correctly, but says that it cannot find the DLL. If I move the DLL to the same directory as the DLL, the exe will run. Is there a way to make my output EXE include the DLL so that I can just move one file to another system and run it without having to send the DLL with the exe.

How can I make this happen in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had the original source code for the .dll, recompiled as a static library (.lib) and then statically linked to it, I don't believe there's a way to "include" the dynamically linked library inside your executable.

Comment: There is! Embed the DLL in the executable as a resource, take it out to disk at startup, and load it dynamically! *Please don't do this*.

Answer (score 0):

You need the DLL in the path, or in the current directory for your application to run. That is how it works with DLLs.

With static libraries, the linking embeds the library code into your application. If you cannot or do not want to have the DLL available, you could change your DLL to a static library.

Comment: Be sure to read the license for your third-party tool (gdal in this case). Some licenses do not take kindly to static linking.

Comment: This one is MIT style so it should be fine.

Comment: True, and there may be other issues that could come up trying to do it as a static library. Just keeping the DLL with the exe is the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are compiling it from source you can just add the source files to your project and build it right into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Post-Build Event in the Visual Studio project that runs a script to copy the DLL to the path of the executable.

Then, when you deploy your application, an installer would be able to take care of the DLL management for you.